# Zipping a file in bash fails

Tags: bash

I have this line of code in a file called `backup.sh`, located in /backup (so the path is /backup/backup.sh)

The code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
zip -r /backup/Backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%d) /ftb
```

The file has permissions 777. However, it errors with:

> -bash: /backup/backup.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

/backup and /ftb both exist. I'm running this as a root user.

Comment: backup.bash or backup.sh?

Comment: Also, write a question please. I am overjoyed that you have this file and that it is not playing hard to execute.

Comment: can you let us know what the error message is?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Backup.sh, my bad. Updated the question.

Comment: You have a \r\n at the end of your first line. @John1024's answer is correct

Comment: Cygwin and notepad? Or just editing the file with Windows line endings enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run dos2unix or similar utility on it to remove the carriage returns (^M).

This message indicates that your file has dos-style lineendings:

```
-bash: /backup/backup.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Utilities like `dos2unix` will fix it:

```
 dos2unix <backup.bash >improved-backup.sh
```

Or, if no such utility is installed, you can accomplish the same thing with translate:

```
tr -d "\015\032" <backup.bash >improved-backup.sh
```

As for how those characters got there in the first place, @MadPhysicist had some good comments.